# Passing the ID with the VF page URL in Global Actions

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, global-actions, publisher-action

In my sfdc 1 i have added a Global Actions to and calling the Vf page. The scenario is : go to all contact tab then select a contact and on that contact select a public action button which we created an it would take the id of the current record and update on a user object. Please guide me the best way I can do this.

Answer (score 1):

How to Create Object and Global Actions is well documented in numerous tutorials provided by Salesforce including the [Salesforce 1 App Developer Guide](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/salesforce1/salesforce1_guide.pdf) and the [Force.com Platform Fundamentals](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/fundamentals/salesforce_creating_on_demand_apps.pdf). Between those two documents, I'd expect you to find the guidance you seek.

If you have a more specific question, then please come back and post for help with it. As your question is currently phrased, it doesn't appear to be specific to a particular issue you're experiencing. If I've misunderstood, please edit your question for clarity and I or others will attempt to provide an answer to your detailed question.